# Qt : issue for displaying IP-CAMERA stream

Tags: c++, qt, rtsp, ip-camera, qmediaplayer

I'm develop a Qt app for displaying my IP-CAMERA stream. It has code similar to  this project : 
https://github.com/cleitonbueno/qt-rtsp-test/tree/widgets

```
    QVideoWidget *_vw1 = new QVideoWidget;

    QMediaPlayer *_player1 = new QMediaPlayer;

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;

    layout->addWidget(_vw1,0,0,1,1);

    QWidget *win = new QWidget();

    win->setLayout(layout);

    setCentralWidget(win);

    _player1->setVideoOutput(_vw1);

    const QUrl url1 = QUrl("rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov");

    const QNetworkRequest requestRtsp1(url1);

    _player1->setMedia(requestRtsp1); 

    _player1->play();
```

When i play Bigbuckbunny video, video's packet is coming and media player plays. But When i write ip camera's rtsp address in Qurl, Media player can't play this stream.
Capture made with Wireshark shows that the rtsp packets are received. But media player is seen black screen.

1. I'm using linux ubuntu 16.04 Gnome 3 (86_64 GNU/Linux)
2. QT 5.10.0
3. QT creator is 4.5

I remove ip camera's username and password. But I also tried with username and password (rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/live/stream1 && rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.1:554/live/stream1).

Can you please help me. I can't understand the root cause of this problem.

Comment: If you can see stream coming up from your camera , but nothing displayed, it tends to say that the format is either incorrect or not handled by the QMediaPlayer. What do you have when you debug ? some Qt class logs stuff in the Debug console; it might contains error/warning poiting you in the right direction

Comment: I have same issue. The error message I get in console is 'Error: "Could not write to resource."'

Comment: Can you try with big buck bunny video. I can't solve this problem on camera. I think the problem seen by to many people who use qt 5.10 or greater version. So i used vlc-qt library. I advice to use it. But i think your problem is different. Your rtsp address may be incorrect. Because your object can't find resource. Can you please give more information about exactly what you did.